# Eclipse indexer errors when using STL with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK r7 with eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu.
I set up my java project to use the C++ nature.
I'm using STL on C++ side so I added

> ```
> APP_STL := gnustl_static
> ```

in the Application.mk file.

ndk-build succeed compiling my code and creating a shared object.

However eclipse indexer complains about missing STL symbols. For example

> "Method 'push_back' could not be resolved" "Symbol 'vector' could not
>   be resolved"

This happens only when C++ files are open in the editor.
Ultimately eclipse won't create my apk.
I added path to the gnu STL headers shiped with the ndk (Properties => C/C++ General => Code Analasys => Path & symbols) :

> ```
> android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include
> android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits
> ```

Current workaround is to close opened C++ files to make eclipse happy.

Interestingly eclipse indexer's working fine with headers found in

> android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include

Is there something I forgot to set up in eclipse ?

Comment: You just shouldn't have added it to Code Analysis but to General->Includes. See my answer.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22935387/1525238 for complete indexing capability in Eclipse.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to add path to STL to project settings so that Eclipse indexes it as well. Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Includes. Here's what I have added:

```
<path_to_NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include
<path_to_NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
<path_to_NDK>/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
```

Comment: I was missing this one
`<path_to_NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/include`
I added it in Properties => C/C++ General => Code Analasys => Path & symbols and it fixed my errors.

Comment: what if developing for all architectures arm x86 and misp ?

Comment: @Safareli: you should probably select only one of them and add it. I guess the headers are largely the same for different architectures, so it shouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: @fnc12: welcome. Find peace in the thought that it was _only_ two hours :)

Answer (score 6):

Some people have been able to fix this problem by adding `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` to Eclipse as mentioned in "[smart pointers not working with Android NDK r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532057/smart-pointers-not-working-with-android-ndk-r8)". But this doesn't work in some versions of Eclipse such as my one (Eclipse Juno v4.2).

So as a work-around hack, I went to Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis, then I changed the severity of some problems from Error to Warning, since I am using NDK to compile my code anyway so these only effect the Indexer. I changed "Symbol is not resolved" and it fixed my errors, but you might also want to change a few others. At first it didn't fix the errors for me until I closed & re-opened the C++ file. Right-clicking on your project and selecting "Index -> Rebuild" might also help refresh it.

Now Eclipse highlights those lines as warnings and allows me to continue building & running & debugging my NDK app.