# OpenCV for android sample programs showing error

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I have downloaded OpenCV project for android and the sample projects that came bundled with it contains several errors....
Only the projects that contain the NDK code has the errors....
The problem is that the C++ code shows many errors...
The keywords like jstring are not recognised..
Kindly help me resolve this issue...
Thanking you in advance for your valuable time

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3View_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray bgra)
{
    jbyte* _yuv  = env->GetByteArrayElements(yuv, 0);
    jint*  _bgra = env->GetIntArrayElements(bgra, 0);

    Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
    Mat mbgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_bgra);
    Mat mgray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);

    //Please make attention about BGRA byte order
    //ARGB stored in java as int array becomes BGRA at native level
    cvtColor(myuv, mbgra, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 4);

    vector<KeyPoint> v;

    FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
    detector.detect(mgray, v);
    for( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
        circle(mbgra, Point(v[i].pt.x, v[i].pt.y), 10, Scalar(0,0,255,255));

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(bgra, _bgra, 0);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(yuv, _yuv, 0);
}

}
```

errors..

```
Unresolved inclusion: <vector>
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
```

Comment: You should post the error messages and the code they correspond to.

Comment: @Michael...please see the edits..

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375708/eclipse-indexer-errors-when-using-stl-with-android-ndk    ?

Comment: @Michael..Yes I am using eclipse...That answer doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: Did you rebuild the index afterwards? Project view -> Index -> Rebuild, or something like that.

Comment: Nope...I haven't done that,should I do that?

Comment: @Michael..Is openCv manager mandatory for all the projects that use OpenCV?

Answer (score 4):

@Nolan's answer followed by @Michael's comment solved it for me. Here are the combined steps:

1. In Eclipse, right click on your project and select properties (This is on a mac btw)
2. Expand **C/C++ General**
3. Select **Paths and Symbols**
4. Under **Languages** select **GNU C++**
5. The following includes should be defined under **Include directories**

   ```
   ${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
   ${ProjDirPath}/../../sdk/native/jni/include
   ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
   ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include
   ```
6. Make sure ${NDKROOT} is defined as an environment variable. If it's not go ahead and add it  under **C/C++ Build - Environment**
7. Now go ahead and rebuild the index by right clicking on your project and select **Index - Rebuild**

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve these and other errors encountered while following the OpenCV tutorial by using the following include paths:

```
${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
${ProjDirPath}/../../sdk/native/jni/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include
```