# smart pointers not working with Android NDK r8

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, android-ndk, smart-pointers

I can't figure out how to use shared pointers within my Android project. I'm using the latest Eclipse ADT on Mac OS X with the Android NDK r8d.

Here is what is in my `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++11
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is what is in my `Application.mk` file:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

I've tried the default GCC 4.6, the experimental 4.7, and the clang3.1 toolchains.
I've tried linking to `stlport_shared` and `gnustl_shared` c++ runtime libraries.
I've tried the `FLAGS` `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++0x`, and the `-std=gnu++11`.

I'm able to use lambdas and auto of the c++11 standard, so the C++11 flag appears to be working. However anytime I try and use a shared_ptr, weak_ptr, or unique_ptr, I get the error `'suchandsuch_ptr' is not a member of 'std'`

I have the `#include <memory>` in my cpp file. Now Eclipse tells me `Unresolved inclusion: <memory>`, but I get the same thing for `<vector>` and `<string>` and those appear to compile and work just fine.

Are smart pointers not implemented in the toolchains included in the Android NDK?
If not, why not? Since GCC and clang have had support for smart pointers for quite some time, this would mean that I am either missing something, or the Android devs have disabled them for some reason.
Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure it won't compile, or it's only the editor not resolving the inclusion? Anyway, the problem is certainly that it's pointing to the old header directory… I remember I had this but I'm not using CDT build any more.

Comment: Its not just the editor not resolving the inclusion. Its also not compiling. But it does compile for <vector> and <string> references even though the editor can't resolve those either. For my project, the gnuc++ include directory is pointing to /android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include

Comment: There should be another include directory which ends in `c++/`. Also, "Are smart pointers not implemented in the toolchains included in the Android NDK?" — as far as I know, GCC 4.7 is not included in the Android NDK. What specifically are you using?

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html, they added the GCC 4.7 compiler to r8d: **"-Added the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) 4.7 compiler to the NDK"**. When I add `/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport` or `/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include` I'm now able to compile! However, I'm still getting IDE errors that say various symbols can't be resolved.

Comment: You'll have to use the indexer settings to choose which toolchain/target settings it uses.

Comment: and that is why people like good ol' normal pointers... because smart pointers are lazy (you know, not working and all).

Comment: @Potatoswatter Awesome. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9376753/1190255, I needed to add some additional paths to get rid of the `<string>` and `<vector>` indexer errors. But the smart pointer indexer errors are still around. I might be missing another path still I suppose.

Comment: @thang Smart pointers aren't lazy, they're a smart way to manage owned pointers. Especially if you use exceptions in your code.

Comment: @BigMacAttack Ah, now I remember, I had to add `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` as a predefined macro to the indexer settings, to emulate `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sure that the standard library include path (like `/android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include`) is in the target settings.

To get the IDE to recognize C++11 classes in the GNU standard library, add `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` as a predefined macro to the indexer. (The name is a bit of anachronism since C++11 is standardized and the support is no longer experimental, but as yet that's what it's called.) Also, be sure the indexer is set to reflect the correct build target.

Comment: Yup. This did it. I can now compile and there are no more indexer errors for c++11 classes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm using Indigo for Android NDK development. I could not find a clear way to "add a predefined macro to the indexer". What is the exact procedure for setting the __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ macro?

Comment: @ArielMalka Preferences => C/C++ => Code Assistance => C++ Compiler => Macro Definitions => Add.

Comment: This didn't fix the Eclipse indexer for me (using Eclipse Juno), so I posted a hack at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375708/eclipse-indexer-errors-when-using-stl-with-android-ndk/15782177#15782177" that worked for me.

Comment: @BigMacAttack how to add library path?

Answer (score 4):

these settings did it for me:

**Application.mk:**

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=-D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__  <--important
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++11
```

**Eclipse Settings:**
C/C++ General\Path and Symbols should contain:

```
C:\android\ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\include
C:\android\ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.7\libs\armeabi\include
```

Comment: that was the "-D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__" ! I thought it would be implied by the -std=c++11, but it works this way ! Thanks

Comment: I have done in the similar manner stated above but i am getting the error           java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol `"_ZNSt13_Filebuf_base12_M_page_sizeE"`.Do you have any idea about the same