# Unique pointer error in ndk

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, g++, smart-pointers

Hi I am always getting this error.

> > error: no type named `unique_ptr` in namespace `std`.

I have tried everything that was discussed in this question, ([smart pointers not working with Android NDK r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532057/smart-pointers-not-working-with-android-ndk-r8)) but error still remains the same. I am unable to follow what the accepted answer says.How to follow these steps in accepted answer "Be sure that the standard library include path (like /android-ndk-r8d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include) is in the target settings."

Comment: General advice for asking questions here: always include examples of what you have tried (in this case, your NDK makefiles).

Comment: Run `ndk-build V=1`, it enables verbose mode, showing compiler command lines as well as other useful stuff.

Comment: Have you used `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11`?

Comment: Note that the 2nd answer provides the code for what the accepted answer suggests.