# android google play game services error : c++ symbol std::function couldn't be resolved

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using NDK-r9d and trying to integrate C++ Google Play Game (GPG) Services to my sample native-activity project.
Now native-activity (sample from NDK ) compiles perfectly and runs fine on my android phone.

But when I add GPG using this code

```
gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration platform_configuration;
platform_configuration.SetActivity(state->activity->clazz);
```

I got error

```
"Symbol 'function' could not be resolved" at achievement_manager.h  /HelloJni/modules/gpg-cpp-sdk/android/include/gpg   line 54 Semantic Error
```

I've added includes to STL and everything needed from this link [Eclipse indexer errors when using STL with Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375708/eclipse-indexer-errors-when-using-stl-with-android-ndk) with no success.

This is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue libgpg-1
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../modules)
$(call import-module,gpg-cpp-sdk/android)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

And this is my Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := c++_static
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us more code, what is line 54? "Symbol 'function' could not be resolved" at achievement_manager.h  /HelloJni/modules/gpg-cpp-sdk/android/include/gpg   line 54

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with compiling gpg sources until I specified the toolchain in Application.mk like this:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Note that I am on SDK 19, google play services 21, and NDK r9d.